# How to check if there is a Notification from Urban Airship in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am having an app in which I am using Urban Airship For push Notification.

I am having a button on my viewController and  clicking on that user can see the notifications from the Inbox of the Urban Airship.

Now I want to check is that If there is no notification from Urban Airship, then my button should get disable and it only needs to be enable if there is a Notification.

So, can I detect if there is a notification or not?

Comment: @SharonNathaniel you should make this an answer, then remove the comment!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you recieve a remote notification from urban airship in -application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: fire a local notification to the view controller that has the button to show the Inbox enabling it, once the user clicks on the button, disable the button and show the inbox, so next time again a notification is recieved your button will be enabled via local notification.